# Eclipse unable to start chrome driver

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng

I am trying to run a maven selenium java base code in Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers but i am getting this issue--->Starting ChromeDriver 73.0.3683.68 (47787ec04b6e38e22703e856e101e840b65afe72) on port 30199

Only local connections are allowed.

Please protect ports used by ChromeDriver and related test frameworks to prevent access by malicious code.

I have tried to downgrade also but still getting the same issue(I have tried with 70 to 75 versions) and my current chrome version is 74

Answer (score 0):

Try with Chrome Driver 74 chrome and chrome driver version is mismatched.so download Chrome Driver 74 and try.